# How do I alter the options in the add menu link checkbox in the node edit form?

Tags: forms, 8, nodes

I am hooking the node edit form with `hook_form_node_page_edit_form_alter()`. How can I alter the available options when adding a menu item for that node?

I need to only show menu items of given node ids:

```
if (isset($form['menu'])) {
  $node_ids = array(1,2,3);
  // only show those node's menu links in the options
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$form['menu']['link']['menu_parent']` is the form array select box for the menu selector widget. `$form['menu']['link']['menu_parent']['#options']` contains the key/value pairs for the menu select box.

In your given example, you can use `unset($form['menu']['link']['menu_parent']['#options']['my_uneeded_menu_id_option']);` to remove your  unneeded menu items.

Comment: I've came that far already, but how do I know which node id is behind each option?

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you know, and what you're specifically asking. The menu `#options` array keys are composite keys containing `<MENU_NAME>:<MENU_ID>`. The `menu_tree` table contains these menu items. If a menu item contains a route referencing a node, it will be listed there. The Menu API might be a better way to retrieve menu items depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've found it out myself, nevermind :) Thanks anyways!